# How to print api response in codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using `Sabare` api in my codeigniter app i want to print API response in my view file but the response is too many steps

so how to print api response using foreach loop thanks in advance

this is the response which i am getting from api

[image]

Comment: this is json response, so you can decode it.

Comment: how to decode this

Comment: use `json_decode()` function for decode

Comment: i have use that already but show an rying to get property 'HotelCode' of non-object

Comment: can you show your code here @ShahidHussain

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the file according to the JSON array, follow the below step.

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://your_api_get_url"));

foreach($data->GetHotelListRS->HotelList->HotelRef[0]->HotelInfo as $hotel) {

  echo $hotel->HotelName;

}
```

Comment: Comment below this answer if it's not working in your case

Comment: Then you can make my answer right for this question and up votes are appreciated @ShahidHussain

Answer (score 0):

try this in php file:

**with row data**

**$data** is php output loop

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$HotelCode = $data->GetHotelListRS->HotelList->HotelRef[0]->HotelInfo[0]->HotelCode;
```

**with form-data**

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
$data = json_encode($response);
$HotelCode = $data['GetHotelListRS']['HotelList']['HotelRef'][0]['HotelInfo'][0]['HotelCode'];
die();
```